# Assetic paths in Symfony 2 dev environment. Paths work, but no styling applied

Tags: less, symfony-2.1, assetic

I'm using assetic with less in Symfony 2 and the MopaBootstrapBundle.

The dynamically generated css file seems to be valid but styling is not applied. If we dump the assets then it does work in prod, but I don't want to do that in dev as that's against the whole point I thought.

**config.yml**:

```
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ MopaBootstrapBundle ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite:     ~
        less:
            node:       /usr/local/bin/node
            node_paths: [/usr/local/lib/node_modules]
            # auto apply less to all .less files
            apply_to:   "\.less$"
```

**config_dev.yml**

```
assetic:
    use_controller: true
```

within my template is:

```
{% stylesheets
    '@MopaBootstrapBundle/Resources/public/less/mopabootstrapbundle.less'
%}
<link href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
```

the rendered html is:

```
 <link href="/app_dev.php/css/bab9907_mopabootstrapbundle_1.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
```

This file resolves, I can paste the URL into the address bar and see a valid CSS file.

Furthermore if we dump assets in prod it also works

```
app/console assetic:dump --env=prod
```

We clear the prod cache and the output is styled. In dev I get zero styling.

I've also ran:

```
app/console assets:install --symlink web
Installing assets using the symlink option
Installing assets for Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle into web/bundles/framework
Installing assets for Mopa\Bundle\BootstrapBundle into web/bundles/mopabootstrap
Installing assets for Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle into web/bundles/webprofiler
Installing assets for Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle into web/bundles/sensiodistribution
```

All this is ditto Javascript (the files resolve when the URLs are followed)

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this too, and i was also using [FosRestBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle) and had it misconfigured:

```
fos_rest:
    format_listener:
        rules:
            - { path: '^/', priorities: ['json', 'html'], fallback_format: html, prefer_extension: true }
```

This rule now applys to EVERY request to the app, and will only know json and html and since .css doesnt match it uses application/json

Correctly it should be:

```
fos_rest:
    format_listener:
        rules:
            - { path: '^/api', priorities: ['json', 'html'], fallback_format: html, prefer_extension: true }                
            - { path: '^/', priorities: [ 'html', '*/*'], fallback_format: html, prefer_extension: true }
```

The last line applies to everything not matched yet, and it tells */* use what was matched internally or something similar intelligent.
And voila `use_controller: true` works again

Answer (score 0):

Did you paste the URL with app_dev.php or without it? If the file really resolves, it should be working, and is not a Sf2 problem. Is your webroot pointing to 'web' dir? If not, try removing the leading '/' in your link href, or change it to the correct path. In dev I usually have something like this:

```
<link href="http://myapp-static.dev/myapp/web/app_dev.php/css/all.css" media="screen" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I preppended an 'assets_base_url' variable (that I defined in twig globals and parameters.yml) and that was the resulting URL. It would have failed if I used '/app_dev.php/css/all.css' instead, because the browser would interpret it as 'http://myapp-static.dev/app_dev.php/css/all.css'

Comment: I definitely pasted the full URL, including app_dev.php. I also have my VHost's webroot point to project_root/web. For now I've just dumped the assets abd will come back to this at a later point

Answer (score 0):

Th Same thing happened to me 
so here is how I resolved it

I have changed this assetic setting in config_dev.yml to this

```
assetic:
    use_controller: false
```

deleted the dev cache and it worked

note: if you are using MAMP then make sure to follow whats in this link

[MopaBootstrapBundle less-installation](https://github.com/phiamo/MopaBootstrapBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/less-installation.md#mac-and-mamp-problems)